# How to access to the '.config' folder on macOS?

Tags: finder, permission, authorization

I need to access to '/Users/marienfarge/.config/NuGet' for a problem with virtual studio but I can't open the folder. (I have a red '-' on the folder)

When I tried to open it :

> Impossible to open the folder '.config' because you don't have the necessary authorization to display his content.

(translate form french so it's maybe not exactly this message for english user)

So I tried to modify the access in the info panel and I give the read & write access for everyone but I still can't open the folder.

Someone told me to wrote this in the terminal : `ls -leO@d /Users/marienfarge/.config/NuGet`

And this is the answer :

```
ls: /Users/marienfarge/.config/NuGet: Permission denied
```

I'm the only user of the Mac and I have the last macOS version.

`ls -leO@d /Users/marienfarge/.config` provides the following result:

```
drwx---rwx  3 root  staff  - 96  9 nov 15:47 /Users/marienfarge/.config
```

Comment: Can you run `ls -leO@d /Users/marienfarge/.config`?

Comment: @nohillside this is the answer : `drwx---rwx  3 root  staff  - 96  9 nov 15:47 /Users/marienfarge/.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access rights for this directory. Run

```
sudo chown marienfarge ~marienfarge/.config
chmod 711 ~marienfarge/.config
```

Comment: How did it get owned by root, I'd want to know.  And that directory is normally mode 711.  Also, why does that tilde construct work?  That should not work!  But it works in ksh and bash.  Sorry, side comment.  Off to read shell documentation...

Comment: Tilde + username expand to the home directory of that user. Thanks for the 711 remark